# Running AysncTask again, once it finished up - onPostExecute()

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I want to run AsyncTask named loadMore again and again in loop trigger via Button named LOAD MORE.

Error:

> 03-07 20:31:38.330: E/AndroidRuntime(504): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot execute task: the task has already been executed (a task can be executed only once

Tried

- Button LOADMORE only be VISIBLE when `onPostExecute()` of loadMore - AsyncTask is executed. Adding LOADMORE view inside `onPostExecute()`.
- Assumed behaviour of AsyncTask is not coming up via LOADMORE button.
- checking whether AysncTask - loadMore RUNNING or not?? inside `onClickListener` of LOADMORE button.
- But as logging information it never reaches the `onClickListener` of LOADMORE button.

onClickListener Code of LOADMORE button::

```
 ld. . . . . .loadMore AsyncTask.
 ll. . . . . . LinearLayout (where I'm removing and Adding LOADMORE button).
 loadMore. . . LOADMORE Button.

public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ll.removeView(loadMore);
        //loadMore.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        spin2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        if(ld.getStatus()==Status.PENDING)
        {
            ld.execute();
            Log.i("PENDING", "Not yet RUNNING");
        }
        else if(true)
        {
            while(ld.getStatus()==Status.RUNNING)
            {
                Log.i("loadMore Async", "LoadMore RUNNING");
                if(ld.getStatus()==Status.FINISHED)
                    return;
            }
            ld.execute();
        }

    }
```

---

onPostExecute() of loadMore AsyncTask ::

```
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
adapter = new PhotosAdapter(MainActivity.this, arrPhotos);
        gridOfPhotos.setAdapter(adapter);

        spin2.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        ll.addView(loadMore);
        Log.i("loadMore-Async", "Adding LoadMore button again");
        Log.i("loadMore-Async", "LoadMore AsyncTask onPost() finished");
        loadMore.setOnClickListener(n);
        Log.i("loadMore-Async", "Adding Listener to LoadMore");
    }
```

Comment: create a new AsyncTask ?

Comment: Why dont you create a service??

Comment: @njzk2 Creating a new loadMore AsyncTask means i need to create it'z object once again??

Comment: @Payal I've already did alot of work with AsyncTask so switching to `Service`is not a good option right now.

Comment: @VikalpPatel create new instance for your asynctask and call exec() method

Comment: yes, because you definitly cannot reuse it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Achieved Through

- Creating a new AsyncTask which would be instantiated dynamically.
- Looping a creating new AysncTask is resolved through creating Array of my loadMore AsyncTask.

Code::

```
loadMorePhotos[] lmd=new loadMorePhotos[1000];
```

onClickListener of LOADMORE button::

```
    View.OnClickListener n=new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ll.removeView(loadMore);
        //loadMore.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        spin2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        if(ld.getStatus()==Status.PENDING)
        {
            ld.execute();
            Log.i("loadMoreAsync", "new AsyncTask : 0");
            Log.i("PENDING", "Not yet RUNNING");
        }
        else if(true)
        {
             Log.i("loadMoreAsync", "Creating new AsyncTask");
             lmd[j]=new loadMorePhotos();
             lmd[j].execute();
             Log.i("loadMoreAsync", "Creating LoadMore AsyncTask :"+j);
             j++;

        }

    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't execute an AsyncTask twice. Citing from the documentation "The task can be executed only once (an exception will be thrown if a second execution is attempted.)", link http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

There is no other option except for making a new task and executing it.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But OP already stated that and I'm finding a way to get through it.